# How to change the sort of a ListView

Tags: python, html, django

Well i want 3 views:

1. show the Pictures with highes rank first(best view)
2. show the newest Pictures first(fresh view)
3. show the best pictures of the newsest first.(trending)

My HTML and view is working, but my sorting dosn't.
Here is what i tryed.

my views.py:

```
class FreshList(SelectRelatedMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = models.Post.objects.order_by('-created_at')
    select_related = ("user", "group")

class BestList(SelectRelatedMixin, generic.ListView):   
    model = models.Post.objects.order_by('ranking')
    select_related = ("user", "group")

class TrendingList(SelectRelatedMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = models.Post.objects.order_by('-created_at','ranking')
    select_related = ("user", "group")
```

Here is my models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='Titel')
    bild = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', default='/static/img/Weramemesicon.png')
    ranking = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

Here is it on Github maybe it helps:https://github.com/TheOneWayTruth/Weramemes

Comment: Why not one view which takes an optional argument which alters the sort order?

Comment: (Also - when defining the same class name twice-  what do you expect to happen?)

Comment: These are the methods i tryed and not my acctual code

Comment: @SaschaWick check solution in my answer. It should help with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Use `queryset` instead `model` in your ListViews:**

```
class FreshList(SelectRelatedMixin, generic.ListView):
    queryset = models.Post.objects.order_by('-created_at')

class BestList(SelectRelatedMixin, generic.ListView):   
    queryset = models.Post.objects.order_by('ranking')

class TrendingList(SelectRelatedMixin, generic.ListView):
    queryset = models.Post.objects.order_by('-created_at','ranking')
```

**Here is explain why `model` its not working with `order_by`:**

> Specifying model = Publisher is really just shorthand for saying
>   queryset = Publisher.objects.all().

[Here you can read rest of Django documentation about model and queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#viewing-subsets-of-objects)

[Source CCBV ListView](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.4/django.views.generic.list/ListView/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the [get_ordering()](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.list/ListView/#get_ordering) method of ListView and leave `model = models.Postmodel`

example:

```
class FreshList(SelectRelatedMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = models.Post
    select_related = ("user", "group")

    def get_ordering(self):
        return "-created_at"
```